# あるユーザーのオンライン状態を判断する方法を教えてください

Tags: javascript, ajax

`setInterval`を用いて一定時間ごとにAJAXリクエストをサーバに送信する方法以外に、あるユーザーのオンライン状態を判断するもっと良い方法はありませんか？

Comment: 質問内容が明確でないので回答がつきづらいかと思いますが、おそらく[Push技術 - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push%E6%8A%80%E8%A1%93)が知りたい内容なのかなと考えます。質問に書かれている方式は、このページにPush技術の対比として書かれているPull技術のうちの"ポーリング"という方式です。

Comment: そもそもどのようなサービスのオンライン状態でしょうか？Webアプリですか？オンラインかどうか確認できるAPIまではできている状態なのですか？`setInterval`を使った方法は既に実装できていると言うことですか？やりたいことの背景をもう少し明確にしないと、どんな手段があるのかを提示することは難しいと思います。